# Extract column definitions from an IXF file of unknown origin

Tags: db2

Suppose someone exported the table `PROPERTIES` using the command:

```
 CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD( 'EXPORT TO /tmp/properties.ixf OF IXF
    MESSAGES ON SERVER select * from properties' );
```

Since then the column order has changed, some were dropped, some added, but I need to load data from that IXF file into the columns that still exist. I don't know what columns the file contains. Running `IMPORT` without mapping them explicitly will fail.

I can only think of loading the file into a temporary table, then create a proper mapping:

```
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD( 'IMPORT FROM /tmp/properties.ixf OF IXF
    MODIFIED BY FORCECREATE ROWCOUNT 0 MESSAGES ON SERVER CREATE INTO TEMP12345' );
```

Problems:

- [IMPORT command options CREATE and REPLACE_CREATE are deprecated](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.wn.doc/doc/i0052280.html)
- `ROWCOUNT 0` not honored in this mode and the data is still loaded from a potentially big file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IXF format [is documented in the manuals](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dm.doc/doc/r0004667.html?lang=en). Conceivably, if other methods don't work as you would like them to, you could write a script to extract column definitions.